# Extract values to point - values not being extracted

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I have a single band raster. When I use the information select tool I can see pixel values. I also have a shape file made up of points sitting over the raster. I want to extract the pixel values from the raster and have those values assigned to each point. I am using Extract values to Point in Arcmap 10.1.  The tool says it runs correctly and the output has a RASTERVALU column added. However all the values are zero, when they should be in the 800s.

Comment: Are the spatial references compatible?

Comment: Thank you Michael. That seems to be the problem. For some reason my point file had lost its reference (although it was still mapping correctly). Starting with a new point file allows the Extract values tool to work. Thanks again.